# Resize UIImageView accordingly to image aspect ratio

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So in my project I use preparesegue to bridge an image from VC1 to VC2. In VC2 there is an image view with left right and top constraints at 0. I want the image view to resize it's height so it maintains the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I want the image view to scale with the image's aspect ratio. so the image view's width is the screen's width. I need the height of the image view to adjust so the image view has the same aspect ratio as the image.

Comment: Again, what is your question? So far you have only made statements about what you want to do. What issue are you having or what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: obviously my question was how do i accomplish that, don't know how you didn't figure that out.

Comment: Of course I know what you meant. I was trying to make a point. You never actually asked a question in your "question".

Comment: Your right. Should've been more clear but I posted this with a lack of sleep. Thanks for wanting to help though, good man.

Comment: @rmaddy needs to review https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let aspect = imageView.image.size.width / imageView.image.size.height
imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.heightAnchor, multiplier: aspect).active = true
```

Comment: i figured it out from that, thanks.